# S3 bucket is not allowing to upload files in laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-s3

We are trying to upload file on amazone s3 bucket but it is not working . File delete and read work fine . but upload not working.

```
 $url = Storage::disk('s3')->url('bulk_pdf_consignments/manifest' . $this->manifest_id . '_.pdf', fopen($bulk_pdf, 'r+'));
```

I think we need add policy but don't know about it.

Comment: is this your upload file code .?

Comment: yes. this is upload file code

Comment: `url()` is to get the url and `put()` is to put file https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#storing-files and both return url path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your upload code has to be something like this:

```
Storage::disk('s3')->put($pathToSaveOn, file_get_contents($request->file->getRealPath()));
```

After upload you can get s3 url this way:

```
$url = Storage::disk('s3')->temporaryUrl($imagePath,now()->addMinutes(10));
```

Note: This code is to upload private file, so, you need to generate temporary url
To upload file publicly you need to pass 3rd argument public

```
Storage::disk('s3')->put($pathToSaveOn, file_get_contents($request->file->getRealPath()), 'public');
```

Comment: i need url in return

Comment: yep, upload it as public, as explained above.

Comment: this is uploading file .but returning me true are false not URL

Comment: after file gets upload, you have to generate url with $url = Storage::disk('s3')->temporaryUrl($imagePath,now()->addMinutes(10));

or $url = Storage::disk('s3')->url($imagePath);